# If a dog licks a surface but this surface has dried and you cannot see any wetness is this surface still classed as najis?

Tags: najis, dogs

if a dog licks a surface such as a bean bag and this surface is not wet anymore is it still classed as dirty? if it is how can i clean it ?

Comment: Why should you clean it? Dirt is not equal to najasah.

Comment: i mean the dogs saliva would be on a surface, is that not classed as najasah?

Comment: Well you've got a link showing that this is a rather baseless claim and contradicts the qur'an itself. Further najasah is related to worship so what role does this item have in your acts of worship?

Comment: So if i touch the bean bag and it was licked by a dog for example and has dried and i come to sit on it and it has touched me does this count as breaking my wudu?

Comment: This is extremely far fetched. Would you smell an odor if the saliva on your hands of touching the dry surface? I'd say no the only case it could happen is if your hand were wet and the saliva not 100% dry. Again howcome we can eat an animal that was brought by a dog  from hunting while the dogs saliva otherwise is regarded as najis.